# How do i cancel the close event from a SmartGWT Window?

Tags: window, smartgwt

How do i cancel the close event from a com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window ? I need the user confirmation to close the window, i saw that the class com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tab.events.TabCloseClickEvent have a cancel method that stops the action, i need the same for the com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.CloseClickHandler. How do i implement this feature?

Comment: Does the kill() method on CloseClickEvent work?

Comment: Nops, it doesn't works, the CloseClickEvent class has no method kill() :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public HandlerRegistration addCloseClickHandler(CloseClickHandler handler)
```

Handles a click on the close button of this window. The default implementation hides the window and returns false to cancel bubbling. Override this method if you want other actions to be taken.

Comment: I've already seen this at the Docs, but That's not the question... the `handler` param doesn't have a `cancel()` method to stop the closing action, understand? Am i wrong?

Comment: @JulioSampaio *Override this method if you want other actions to be taken*.. Which means, override it, and do whatever you wanna do

Comment: ok, but i don't see the way to cancel the closing action, what Window's class method should i use? Have you ever done something like this with SmartGwt?

`@Override
 public HandlerRegistration addCloseClickHandler(CloseClickHandler handler) {
  
  SC.confirm("Close window?", new BooleanCallback() {     
   @Override
   public void execute(Boolean value) {
    if(value){
     //what to do to cancel the closing?
    }
   }
  });
  //what should it return?
  return super.addCloseClickHandler(handler);
 }`

Comment: yes. to avoid cancel do nothing, otherwise just hide() the window, or as you say, call super method

Answer (score 0):

In your window object

```
    myWindowObject.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {  
            public void onCloseClick(CloseClickEvent event) {  

                    //Do whatever

                    if(IHaveTOCancel){
                            event.cancel();
                    }
                }  
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you don't immediately cancel the event (because it's waiting for user input) then the window closes anyway. Here is what I found worked if you need to wait for user input.

```
window.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onCloseClick(CloseClickEvent event) {
            event.cancel();
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.append("<BR>");
            b.append("Are you sure you want to close?");
            SC.ask("Close", b.toString(), new BooleanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Boolean value) {
                    if (value) {
                        window.close();
                    } 
                }
            });
        }
    });
```